# Scala: Why java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date?

Tags: java, scala, date, date-formatting

I have the following simple code that leads to a `RuntimeException` error that I can't explain:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.commons.cli._
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

object TestMain {
  def doFormat(value: Any): String = {
    val ClassOfDouble = classOf[Double]
    val ClassOfDate = classOf[Date]
    val ClassOfDateTime = classOf[DateTime]
    val result: String = value.getClass match {
      case ClassOfDouble => MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#.####################}", Array(value.asInstanceOf[DateTime]))
      case ClassOfDate => MessageFormat.format("{0,date,yyyy.MM.dd}", Array(value.asInstanceOf[Date]))
      case ClassOfDateTime => DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:SSS").print(value.asInstanceOf[DateTime])
      case _ => value.toString
    }
    result
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(doFormat(new Date()))
  }
}
```

... and the resulting runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at test.TestMain$.doFormat(TestMain.scala:28)
    at test.TestMain$.main(TestMain.scala:39)
    at test.TestMain.main(TestMain.scala)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're passing an `Array` to the `format` method. You can simply use the `Date` directly:

```
case ClassOfDate => MessageFormat.format("{0,date,yyyy.MM.dd}", value.asInstanceOf[Date])
```

With this, the output will be:

> 2017.10.17

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to wrap the second argument of the MessageFormat.format() with an Array since it requires a vararg.

Call with Array is confusing. It is unclear if Array is vararg (Object...) or just a first argument of vararg (Object). It uses the second and you encounter with an Exception.